# data.table use all columns to make string

Tags: r, data.table

I have downloaded data from [lending club](https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action) and loaded it into R using `data.table`'s `fread()` function.

For each row, I would like data.table to collect all of the information from all of the columns and put it into a single string, in the most efficient manner possible. My current function works, but think that this is probably quite slow and could deal with some improvement from some data.table experts on SO.

```
foo <- function(y, dt_obj, col_names=colnames(dt_obj)){
   paste0("http://localhost:8080/predict?",
          paste0(col_names,"=",unlist(dt_obj[y,],use.names=FALSE),
                 collapse="&")
          )
 }
```

In the above function, `y` is the row number, the `dt_obj` is the csv data that was read into R using fread.

I then go through each row and add in the data to my original data.table object `dt` using the following line

```
dt[,strg:=sapply(seq(nrow(dt)),function(x){foo(x,dt_obj=dt)})]
```

However this seems to take a while and believe that the speed could be improved if a more efficient `foo` function were created or data.table was used in a more efficient manner...

As always any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I have a very naive suggestion. Did you try removing the column delimiter while reading the CSV? Rows should be read correctly, and the commas separating the fields would be considered as text.

Comment: your link is blocked from my location. I posted sample data if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, quite neat...but unfortunately, for my situation, the csv data is just an example...my data is already in R which is normally read in using readRDS as it is an RDS format.

Comment: Could you add an example dataset and output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `data.table` for something that isn't using its unique strengths. Here's a straightforward matrix method with `base R` that took 3.5 seconds when I downloaded the dataset from Lending Club:

```
system.time({
mat <- as.matrix(dt)
a <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) paste(colnames(mat), unlist(x), sep="="))
newvec <- paste0("http://localhost:8080/predict?", apply(a, 2, paste, collapse="&"))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.50    0.03    3.54 

#compare to your original function
system.time(
+ dt[,strg:=sapply(seq(nrow(dt)),function(x){foo(x,dt_obj=dt)})]
+ )
#   user  system elapsed 
# 135.45    0.03  136.02

all.equal(newvec[1], dt[1,strg])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the use of matrices is good, but I wanted to keep the character strings, which i think get converted in your example...

Comment: They are character strings. What conversion are you referring to?